# How to display mysql table records as a navigation in bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and mysql, and am trying to display a table which has several records, to my list group in a way that I should be able to click each record and navigate to another page. I want your helps with the codes.
Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </div>


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

              <?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM categories LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $title = $row['title'];
   $id = $row['id'];

    echo "<li><a href='category.php?category={$id}'>{$title}</a></li>";
}

?>



            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: What I meant was: how can I display my table (in database) that has 9 records, as a link table in website? where I can click each record and take me to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Put this data or call it via making it function or class in `<table><tr>..</tr></table>`

```
<?php 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $title = $row['title'];
       $link = $row['link'];

        echo "<td><a href='category.php?data={$link}'>{$title}</a></td>";
    }

?>
```